# why is the estimated time not changing?

Tags: etherdelta

My ETH transaction is not yet confirmed and still pending, its been 4hrs ago I am transferring it to Etherdelta. Earlier the estimated transaction time is 4hrs and 6mins and 45seconds but it has been that long but still the estimated transaction time is the same, can you help me with this please? here is my Transaction hash:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07e2309bd3d191014ee2b1aa909d9d03e3bfa8f7813fba1a37b5a19cea93ad68
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your gas price is way too low, [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) says it will take in average about 8.5 hours, your price is 4Gwei the average is 9Gwei. It will work, but you will have to wait.